# What is a 'detection' in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-detectors

I don't know about QFT. However, I imagined that in a filed, there's a probability distribution for excitations. Say there are two electrons somewhere - two excitations somewhere in the EM field, so there should be some non-zero probability almost everywhere (maybe limited by c) for the electrons to be detected? But say one of the electrons is used in a double-slit experiment and is 'detected' on a screen, then at the time of the detection there is 100% probability for the electron to be detected in a very small region but 0% probability to be detected elsewhere? How is a 'detection' different than the self-evolution of a field, where it seems that some non-zero probability always exists for the electron to be detected elsewhere? Are the two elctrons 'detecting' each other?

Comment: Electrons are not excitations of the EM field. *Photons* are excitations of the EM field. Electrons are excitations of the *electron field*.

Comment: Electrons interact with each other but do not “detect” each other. Detection/observation/measurement is what we call an interaction with a macroscopic classical measuring device.

Comment: @G.Smith The 'device' you mentioned also may also just work by single electrons interacting with each other (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UguFUpcV5Ew&t=112s). How does this interaction differ from other electron interactions?

Comment: I don’t have time to watch the video. There is more to the device than two electrons.

Comment: The video is just a reference about the device you mentioned. My argument stands without it. Any 'macroscopic measuring device' is composed of these micro things. It all comes down to the electrons or whatever other elementary particles involved interacting with each other after all. The logic doesn't automatically give a magic threshold why if there's 10^10 particles it's a measurement but if there's 2 it's not.

Comment: I assume you are aware than entire books have been written about the “measurement issue” in quantum mechanics. When people are interested in this subject (I’m not), I always suggest studying decoherence theory for more insight into what a “classical measuring device” is doing quantum mechanically.

Comment: There is no magic threshold between quantum physics and classical physics, but you can consider $\hbar$ to set the scale (of a quantity called the action) on which quantum effects are relevant.

Comment: I think most physicists agree that ultimately “it’s all quantum mechanics”. Anything else is just a useful approximation. Often it is too hard to extract useful results from QM, and we are fortunate to (mostly) live in a more-easily-understood classical limit of it.

Comment: Somewhat, the 'measurement' seems to be defined from an observer's point of view. (I study little physics so it's just a conjecture.) So if the observer is included in a system, the wave function of the system would not change if the observer within measures something within, but the wave function of something within according to the observer would be changed (collapsed) if the observer measures the thing.

Comment: I believe there are interpretations of QM where this is the case, and other interpretations where it isn’t. They all give the same answer so a lot of physicists just don’t care. I’m getting a message to avoid an extended discussion, so I’ll stop.